# Can array of primitive data type be instantiated?

Tags: java, arrays, primitive, abstract-data-type

When creating an array of a class in java there are three steps: Declaration, instantiation and initiation.
But when creating an array of **primitive data types**, does the *new* keyword instantiate or initiate?

I found it confusing as in many places the word instantiate is used only for array of a class/classes. So, i want to know if the step of instantiating is also used for array of **PRIMITIVE** data type. Or, is it that the whole statement of initiating an array is as shown below.

```
int intArray[];    //declaring array
intArray = new int[20];  // allocating memory to array
```

Comment: Well, from my point of view, it doesnt matter at all, how you will call it, `if you will make instance of class, then you are doing initialization of an object`, and  you need allocate the memory anyway. So, theoretically and on the pure abstract level, its being both in this case, I would say. I dont think so there is any common or right answer.

Comment: An array type is **always** an object, even if its *component type* is a primitive, see [JLS, chapter 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-10.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java , when we instantiate a primitive array (like `new int[10]`), items in the array are initialized with default value of that primitive. (Default value for `int` is `0`, default value for `boolean` is `false` etc.)

When we instantiate an object array (e.g. `String` array), items in the array are initialized with `null`.

See below program and its output.

```
public class PrimitiveArray
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] intArray = new int[10];
    boolean[] booleanArray = new boolean[10];
    String[] stringArray = new String[10];

    System.out.println("intArray[3] = " + intArray[3]);
    System.out.println("booleanArray[3] = " + booleanArray[3]);
    System.out.println("stringArray[3] = " + stringArray[3]);
  }
}
```

Output is:
`intArray[3] = 0`
`booleanArray[3] = false`
`stringArray[3] = null`

Answer (score 3):

> Can array of primitive data type be instantiated?

Yes.

> Does the `new` keyword in `new int[20]` instantiate or initiate?

In that example, it both *instantiates* the primitive array and *initializes* it<sup>1</sup> to the *default* value for the primitive type; i.e. zero for an array of a primitive numeric type and `false` for an array of `boolean`.

On the other hand:

```
int intArray[];
```

is *declaring* an array variable and not either initializing the variable, or instantiating an array.  If that is a local variable declaration, the compiler won't let you use the variable until it is assigned to.  If it is a field, then the variable will be default initialized to `null`; i.e. no array is instantiated.

Java does not allow a program to access a variable or array element that has not been initialized, either explicitly or by *default* initialization.  This is a fundamental property of the language.

---

<sup>1 - The correct term is *initialize* NOT *initiate*.  Initiate (in English) means either "to begin" (e.g. an action or process) or "to admit (someone) into a secret or obscure society or group, typically with a ritual.". This not the correct meaning in this context.</sup>